# Apache virtualhosts editing not responding

Tags: webserver, apache2, virtual-hosts

How is it possible for an Apache web server to not have any entries in its `/etc/apache/sites-enabled` directory but still serve websites?

I am running an Apache web server on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I have more than 20 websites responding correctly on this server.
Recently I decided to implement a Drupal multisite and that took me to `/etc/apache/sites-available` to edit the `000-default.conf`. It is the only .conf file available and has the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined                  
</VirtualHost>
```

This handles serving for all the websites on my server but in attempting to debug why a second `.conf` file does not work, I altered the DocumentRoot to `/var/www2`, a directory which does not exist.

Once I had saved the document and restarted Apache, I found my websites still loading successfully.

I disabled the 000-default.conf virtualhost, expecting that my websites would stop loading, but they still worked.

Just to be certain, I stopped Apache and all my websites stopped responding, but right now all my websites are responding from an Apache server which has no entries in the sites-enabled directory?

Appreciating that getting things to STOP working is the very opposite of what forums are for, I am trying to understand why my websites are still loading even with all virtualhosts disabled so I can begin solving other problems.

Comment: Isn't it a cache issue (client or server side)? What do your logs mention about your last requests?

Answer (score 0):

The main server configuration acts like a catch-all virtual-host, until an actual VirtualHost override it.  IOW, Explicit virtual hosts are not required to process requests.